# Emulate Excel Numeric Precision C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, vba, math

## Excel Precision system

Excel has a modified version of the IEEE 754 specification for numeric precision. More information on how Excel does calculation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel).

### Summarizing:

- Numbers are stored with only it's 15 leading figures.
- Before any calculation Excel tries to represent the number as power of 2 (because of it's binary representation)
- If the number is not a simple power of 2, it uses geometric progression to find the closest number represented by binary.
- If the number is really small Excel represents it as a simple power of 2.

---

## Problem

Other languages, in my case **C# .NET**, implement numeric precision in a different way. 
So, when you try to emulate a Spreadsheet, you end up getting some precision mismatches.

### Example

Open Excel and insert this formula in any cell:

```
=1+1/9000-1.
```

Then you will notice that the result is not the same as the one that is obtained by the following formula:

```
=1/9000
```

**I don't want to change this behavior of Excel, i just want to mimic it.**

Now in C# create a simple program and do the same calculation with a `Decimal` number. *I'm using decimal to represent numbers. But it could be double our Float, the result will be the same.*

```
decimal result = 1.0M + 1.0M / 9000.0M - 1.0M;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("N30"));
```

### Question

**Is there any Way that C# can emulate Excel's numeric precision. So that i can get the same results as Excel?**

## Edit

As @DStanley mentioned, using double solves the example above, but it stills doesn't work for other situations, for example:

Excel:

```
=1+0.000000000000001665280326829110-1

0.000000000000000000000000000000
```

C#:

```
double result = 1.0 + 0.000000000000001665280326829110 - 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("N30"));

0.000000000000001554312234475220
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate floating-point math then use `double` instead of `decimal`. `decimal` is designed to give a more accurate base-10 representation at the expense of speed. If you use `double` in C# you get the same result as Excel (at least for your examples - there may be other edge cases that behave differently):

C#:

```
double result = 1.0 + 1.0 / 9000.0 - 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("N30"));

0.000111111111111173000000000000
```

Excel:

```
=1+1/9000-1

0.000111111111111173000000000000
```

Comment: It Worked! but for other situations it still gives wrong answers. How could i fix it?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific - what situations?  does a difference in the 14th or 15th decimal really matter that much?

Comment: I have edited my question, in the end there is an Example. Actually I'm developing an application for an financial institution that is used to do calculation with excel, so minor errors can propagate.